# Why there is difference by 16 byte between allocated variables' addresses?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why is there aligment to 8 bytes (and 16 on 64bit systems)? What are reasons for such alignment?

**Example:**

```
int* ptr1 = new int;
int* ptr2 = new int;
int* ptr3 = new int;

cout << ptr1 << " " << ptr2 << " " << ptr3 << endl;
cout << ptr2 - ptr1 << endl;
```

Outputs:

```
0x15cbc20 0x15cbc40 0x15cbc60  
8
```

Comment: Actually, looking at the output you provided, the ints you allocated are 32 bytes apart.

Comment: Totally depends on what memory allocation algorithm is used. It's unlikely that allocated chunks exactly match the requested size of a type, but are at least aligned, or grabbing a minimal memory chunk as used with the default allocator.

Comment: Alignment is done so CPUs can read from main memory faster

Comment: The pointer difference isn't 8 bytes, but 8 ints. Anyway, allocating only some sizes, like 32, 64, or 128 bytes might improve allocation speed and minimize memory fragmentation. Who allocates single ints on the heap anyway?

Comment: You need a book on how computers work! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually two things are *typically* responsible :

- Alignment (Other answers dealt with this)
- Bookkeeping information

When you request 4 bytes (for example) of memory, your underlying memory allocator (whatever is used by the selected `operator new(...)`) may use some extra bytes to store some bookkeeping information. See a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16624732/1621391)

The bookkeeping information is usually why `delete` works without having to tell it the original size of memory requested.

For example:

```
void* Malloc(std::size_t size){
     //Allocator searches for free memory
     auto FreeList = GetNextFreeNodeOfAtLeast(size + 16);

     //Rounds the requested size to the ceil of CPU word size
     size = RoundToWordAlignment(size);

     //Allocate with an extra 16 bytes for bookkeeping
     void* Memory = FreeList->Allocate(size + 16);

     //Use the Upper 16bytes... some implementations use lower..
     auto info = static_cast<MallocInformation*>(Memory + size);

     //Create an Info object so that `Free` or operator delete can use to free memory
     new(info) MallocInformation(size, FreeList, ....);

     //Return the Memory
     return Memory;
}
```

Each memory allocated to you has some backlogged information attached to it. There are many different ways memory allocators work, some have bookkeeping information of a single pointer to some master Structure where memory is managed.

The C++ standard doesn't require successive memory allocations to be contiguous, neither does it specify how much memory "gap" between them.

Comment: CPU word is 2 bytes, am I right?
So this alignment is not so significant for the overheading size. Or there is some additional alignment, not only to word?

Answer (score 3):

```
int* ptr1 = new int;
int* ptr2 = new int;
int* ptr3 = new int;
```

1st there's no guarantee that these statements will allocate contigous memory addresses regarding the `sizeof(int)`.

> What are reasons for such alignment?

Because CPU's have caches to access heap allocated data, and these caches are optimized to use byte aligned access for either 32 or 64 bit pointers, depending on the target architecture.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that dynamically allocated objects would be stored adjacently at all (even in adjacent aligned address). The fact that your allocator happened to allocate memory `8*sizeof(int)` (32 on your system) bytes apart is an implementation detail.

`operator new` is typically (although not guaranteed to, this is another implementation detail) implemented with using `malloc`. There is no way to request particular alignment when allocating memory with `malloc`. That is why it is guaranteed to allocate memory *suitably aligned for any built-in type* i.e. to `sizeof(maxalign_t)` boundary. So, for a typical implementation, I would not find an alignment of 8 or 16 bytes unexpected.